# how to access picture stored in database via http request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, http

As per title. And is there anyway to cache such data?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
class SomeController
  def avatar
    user = User.find(1)
    send_data user.avatar_data, 
      :type => user.avatar_content_type, 
      :disposition => 'inline'
  end
end
```